# Expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant? This is weird

Tags: c

I am running into a really weird error. Commenting out the below pieces of code lets my program run. Keeping it in, gives me the error.

In my functions .c file:

```
int validateArgs(int MIN_INPUT, int MAX_INPUT, int argc)
{
    if ((argc < MIN_INPUT) || (argc > MAX_INPUT))
    {
        printf("Wrong input.");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I have all constants in a header file.

Constants are 0 and 9.

Comment: Do you also have a function called `validatekArgs` defined somewhere, or is it just `validateArgs`

Comment: Your method name is defined as `validateArgs`, but you call it as `validatekArgs` later (notice the extrac "k").

Comment: @cleblanc Even with that fixed, same error, besides it would have given me a different error, so it doesn't seem like that's the issue.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ See above comment.

Comment: `int validateArgs(int MIN_INPUT, int MAX_INPUT, int argc)` expands to `int validateArgs(int 0, int 9, int argc)` with those `#define`s... are `0` or `9` valid parameter names?

Comment: ***"This question was caused by a simple typographical error."*** -  Voting to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
int validateArgs(int MIN_INPUT, int MAX_INPUT, int argc)
```

translates as

```
int validateArgs(int 0, int 9, int argc)
```

because of your constant definitions. That is not correct C syntax and probably not what you want.

Comment: You're right, I've made those local variables and just stored the constants into the local variables and now it works, thanks.

Comment: I believe you might still be confusing local variables and formal parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Your validate args method is ok except for the return type. Change to boolean/bool or whatever is used to represent true/false values in C.

I'm sorry but I am a java dev.

```
boolean validateArgs(int MIN_INPUT, int MAX_INPUT, int argc)
{
    if ((argc < MIN_INPUT) || (argc > MAX_INPUT))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Input must be between 1 and 7, inclusive, digits.");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Hope your problem was solved.

**EDIT:** I did not know MIN_INPUT is a declared constant. And probably, I also didn't really understand the question. Sorry.